# Google PubSub does not trigger Function with each new message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Google PubSub stream that has a set of addresses added to it each day. I want each of these addresses processed by a triggered Google Cloud Function. However, what I have seen is that each address is only processed once even though there is a new message added to the stream each day.

My question is, if the same value is added to a stream each day will it be processed as a new message? Or will it be treated as a duplicate message?

This is the scenario I am seeing. Each day the `locations` Cloud Function is triggered and publishes each location to the `locations` topic. Most of the time these are the same messages as the previous day. The only time they change is if a location closes or there is a new one added. However, what I see is that many of the `locations` messages are never picked up by the `location_metrics` Cloud Function.

The flow of the functions is like this:

Topic is triggered each day at 2a (called `locations_trigger`) > triggers `locations` Cloud Function > sends to `locations` topic > triggers `location_metrics` Cloud Function > sends to `location_metrics` topic

For the `locations` Cloud Function, it is triggered and returns all addresses correctly then sends them to the `locations` topic. I won't put the whole function here because there are no problems with it. For each location it retrieves there is a "publish successful" message in the log. Here is the portion that sends the location details to the topic.

```
        project_id = "project_id"
        topic_name = "locations"
        topic_id = "projects/project_id/topics/locations"

        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

        try:
            publisher.publish(topic_path, data=location_details.encode('utf-8'))
            print("publish successful: ", location)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
```

An example `location` payload that is sent is:
`{"id": "accounts/123456/locations/123456", "name": "Business 123 Main St Somewhere NM 10010"}`

The `location_metrics` function looks like:

```
def get_metrics(loc):
    request_body = {
      "locationNames": [ loc['id'] ],
      "basicRequest" : {
              "metricRequests": [
                 {
                   "metric": 'ALL',
                   "options": ['AGGREGATED_DAILY']
                 }
              ],
              "timeRange": {
                   "startTime": start_time_range,
                   "endTime": end_time_range,
              },
        }
    }

    request_url = <request url> 
    report_insights_response = http.request(request_url, "POST", body=json.dumps(request_body))

    report_insights_response = report_insights_response[1]
    report_insights_response = report_insights_response.decode().replace('\\n','')
    report_insights_json = json.loads(report_insights_response)

            <bunch of logic to parse the right metrics, am not including because this runs in a separate manual script without issue>

            my_data = json.dumps(my_data)

            project_id = "project_id"
            topic_name = "location-metrics"
            topic_id = "projects/project_id/topics/location-metrics"

            publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
            topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

            print("publisher: ", publisher)
            print("topic_path: ", topic_path)
            try:
                publisher.publish(topic_path, data=gmb_data.encode('utf-8'))
                print("publish successful: ", loc['name'])
            except Exception as exc:
                print("topic publish failed: ", exc)

def retrieve_location(event, context):
    auth_flow()
    message_obj = event.data
    message_dcde = message_obj.decode('utf-8')
    message_json = json.loads(message_dcde)

    get_metrics(message_json)
```

Comment: Pubsub processes messages as a messages. There isn't duplicate removal or other strange stuff according to the day.

Your issue can come from another reason. May be in your code. Or the method that you use to check the message processing is wrong.

Comment: Does the explanation from documentation pages about [executing guarantees](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees) answer your question?

Comment: @Nick_Kh That isn't it. After the first time, no new messages are processed. Its as if after the address is sent once the same address is never processed again.

Comment: @analyticsPierce, Can you explain how do you trigger the particular cloud function?

Comment: @Nick_Kh I added some detail to help clarify.

Comment: @analyticsPierce, Have you tried to re-deploy `location_metrics` cloud function? For mine given partial code looks fine.